# Block builder errors with missing bot scopes, but the scopes are present

Tags: slack-api

i am using the block kit builder to format a video preview, i followed the instructions at https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks#video and using a youtube.com url it works fine.
However when i use my own domain url, i get an error:

`Video validation failed: Bot scopes missing: [links:read, links:write, and/or links.embed:write]`

My bot scopes are correct and include all of these scopes.  My domain is listed in the unfurl list.  I have re-installed the app into my workspace each time after changing scopes.

I am out of ideas for things to change or try.